# C# querying new relic

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp, newrelic

Does anyone know how to talk to the new relic rest APIs? For example, I am using selenium to automate functional tests against an environment that is being monitored by new relic for both frontend and backend. Basically, I run my test and then I check new relic to analyze performance. Is it possible to query and retrieve certain data from new relic using c# in visual studio? And how do I do that and where do I start. Is there sample code? Also, how do I tag my test run and get data from new relic specific to that test run?

Comment: Is this the API you want to query https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/insights/insights-api/get-data/query-insights-event-data-api ?

Comment: Yes. Perfect. How do I tag a specific run

Comment: What is the NRQL you want to run? https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/insights/nrql-new-relic-query-language/using-nrql/introduction-nrql

Comment: Any nrql would be fine @mjwills